# Crystal reports stretch page 2

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have a report which needs to be printed on 2 pages and the second-page contents are 3 sub reports in the group footer section of main report. However, the contents of page 2 will not fit the complete page where I need the background/contents to be stretched to the whole page.

Any suggestions ?? 
[i want this to be stretched to the whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LQTz.jpg)

Comment: is it possible to show us the screen shot of the designer and page 2 report ? If data is not test data or sensitive, You may black out the data in report before showing us the image.

Comment: I have added the image of page 2 report.

Comment: I suggest a) check 'print at bottom of page' for additional group footer section b) surround your too short sub-report (placed in first group footer section) with box over both group footer sections (and remove subreport border). Note that I didn't check, does that work or not - thereby comment only.

Comment: Thanks @Arvo ... it worked !!